# Weblogic Guava issue when deploying application

Tags: java, deployment, weblogic, guava

I'm trying to deploy an application to a weblogic server, and I get the following error.
 I have guava.jar in my classpath, I tried with all the latest versions I tried from 10 and up. Can somebody help me out with this?

```
    <Error> <Console> <BEA-240003> <Administration Console encountered the following error: weblogic.application.ModuleException: [HTTP:101216]Servlet: "action" failed to preload on startup in Web application: "...".
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.sameThreadExecutor()Lcom/google/common/util/concurrent/ListeningExecutorService;
            at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.<clinit>(LocalCache.java:155)
            at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache.<init>(LocalCache.java:4750)
            at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.<init>(LocalCache.java:4858)
            at com.google.common.cache.CacheBuilder.build(CacheBuilder.java:739)
            at com.my.app.servers.UserServer.<clinit>(UserServer.java:42)
            at com.my.app.ActionServlet.setAppProperties(DesActionServlet.java:207)
            at com.my.app.ActionServlet.init(DesActionServlet.java:167)
            at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:240)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:299)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:250)
            at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
            at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
            at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.initServletInstance(StubSecurityHelper.java:94)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.createServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:82)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.createOneInstance(StubLifecycleHelper.java:74)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.<init>(StubLifecycleHelper.java:60)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.<init>(StubLifecycleHelper.java:34)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.initStubLifecycleHelper(ServletStubImpl.java:624)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.prepareServlet(ServletStubImpl.java:565)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadServlet(WebAppServletContext.java:1874)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.loadServletsOnStartup(WebAppServletContext.java:1848)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1738)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:2740)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1704)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:781)
            at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:213)
            at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:208)
            at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:35)
            at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:70)
            at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.start(ScopedModuleDriver.java:212)
            at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:111)
            at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
            at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:213)
            at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:208)
            at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:35)
            at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:70)
            at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:24)
            at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:729)
            at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:35)
            at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:258)
            at weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.activate(SingleModuleDeployment.java:48)
            at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:165)
            at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:79)
            at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:582)
            at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:148)
            at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:114)
            at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:335)
            at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:844)
            at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1253)
            at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:440)
            at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:163)
            at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:195)
            at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
            at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:68)
            at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:545)
            at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
            at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
```

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.sameThreadExecutor()Lcom/google/common/util/concurrent/ListeningExecutorService;
```

Comment: What puzzles me is that some guava classes are present. Are you using  ProGuard ? What is you build system ?

Comment: using eclipse, and deploying on weblogic console.

Comment: UPDATE!! in the end i got the problem with the solution  from @Chris Povirk
 but i got it solved [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13386474/are-guava-11-0-2-jar-conflicting-with-com-google-common-1-0-0-0-0-6-jar)

Answer (score 11):

It looks like you're running against a different version of Guava than you compiled against. Possibly you are running against *multiple* versions of Guava, and you are randomly getting the wrong one. This may be happening if one of your other dependencies has wrongly bundled Guava.

To figure out where this copy of `MoreExecutors` is coming from, I've heard that you can find it reflectively by using this snippet in `UserServer`:

```
MoreExecutors.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation()
```

Comment: No idea what i should do, can you give me more details ? tnx a mill!

Comment: @ElyeM. Add something like `System.out.println(MoreExecutors.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation())` (or using your logging system of choice) either in a static initialization block in `com.my.app.servers.UserServer` or more probably in `com.my.app.ActionServlet.init()` before line 167, so it executes before the exception is thrown. That will log the "path" of the jar which contains the loaded `MoreExecutors` class and help you get rid of the jar conflict.

Comment: Okay first thanks! I did it and its coming from com.google.common_1.0.0.0_0-6.jar and it has to come from Guava-11.0.2.jar , what do you think I should do? I think I can’t just delete the com.google.common_1.0.0.0_0-6.jar file cuz its needed for the server, do you have any suggestions ?

Comment: You could try the weblogic-application.xml suggestion under "Clazzloading or Oracle and RedHat vs. Google" at http://blog.eisele.net/2011/12/running-richfaces-410final-on-weblogic.html

Comment: @ElyeM. the solution linked by Chris should solve your issue, as it's a classloading problem: WLS packages what looks like an old & repackaged version of google-collections, which has been superseded by Guava; By default, your application will "see" the classes loaded by WLS before the ones it packages, which is why you end up using the wrong `MoreExecutors` version. By filtering the packages exported by Guava from the application classloader, you'll be sure to use all the Guava classes coming from the jar packaged in your app, not the one in WLS itself.

Comment: try my answer at this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17976553/2098832)  
should work for you as well. It uses weblogic.xml and FilteringClassloaders from WebLogic instead of jar replacement...

Answer (score 2):

It seems this a recurring question ([[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9688207/guava-and-weblogicclassnotfoundexception), [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19625086/guava-15-0-jar-conflict-in-weblogic-12c/28774640), [[3]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13386474/are-guava-11-0-2-jar-conflicting-with-com-google-common-1-0-0-0-0-6-jar)). I, myself, have stumbled upon this same problem. Weblogic is loading first it's own version of the (outdated) guava lib confliting with your applcation's version.

The solution is to add the `prefer-application-packages` to your `weblogic.xml` or `weblogic-application.xml`:

```
<wls:container-descriptor>
    <wls:prefer-application-packages>
            <wls:package-name>com.google.common.*</wls:package-name>
    </wls:prefer-application-packages>
</wls:container-descriptor>
```

Answer (score 1):

Is it a WAR project? Or is it just a EJB jar?

If the latest one, you've got a few options:

- wrap your jar file into a EAR and deliver Guava's jar in it
- add Guava's jar to the library folder of your AS
- merge your jar file with Guava's one. For example, you can use [Maven Shade Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) if you're a Maven guy

Answer (score 1):

I faced the similar issue. I could resolve this problem by adding a weblogic-application.xml with prefer-application-packages to my EAR.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<weblogic-application xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application"
                      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"                            xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application/1.0/weblogic-application.xsd">
    <prefer-application-packages>
        <package-name>com.google.common.*</package-name>
    </prefer-application-packages>
</weblogic-application>
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this problem using both files: weblogic-application.xml in ear and weblogic.xml in war

This is weblogic-application.xml in ear -> src/main/application/META-INF/

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wls:weblogic-application
    xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/javaee_5.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application/1.4/weblogic-application.xsd">
    <wls:prefer-application-packages>
        <wls:package-name>com.google.common.*</wls:package-name>
    </wls:prefer-application-packages>
</wls:weblogic-application>
```

This is weblogic.xml in war -> src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wls:weblogic-application
    xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/javaee_5.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application/1.4/weblogic-application.xsd">
    <wls:prefer-application-packages>
        <wls:package-name>com.google.common.*</wls:package-name>
    </wls:prefer-application-packages>
</wls:weblogic-application>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran across this issue as well, unfortunately altering the weblogic.xml didn't work for me. What did work, was dropping the guava-14.0.1.jar into $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/endorsed (create this directory if it doesn't exist.)

One other word of caution: at first I tried using the more recent guava-18 - this caused a compatibility issue the other way (IllegalAccessError on MapMaker.makeComputingMap - more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23957409/ava-lang-illegalaccesserror-tried-to-access-method-com-google-common-collect-ma)). Guava 14.0.1 seems to hit the sweet spot for me - the MapMaker class is old enough to satisfy WebLogic while the MoreExecutors class is new enough to make the Cassandra Java driver work (which is how I stumbled upon this issue.)