# java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.google.common.collect.MapMaker.makeComputingMap(); from WeldMessageConveyor

Tags: java, gwt, weblogic, gxt, errai

I get the following exception when I try deploying my webApp on weblogic12:

```
weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.google.common.collect.MapMaker.makeComputingMap(Lcom/google/common/base/Function;)Ljava/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap; from class org.jboss.weld.logging.WeldMessageConveyor
at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:140)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:213)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:208)
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.google.common.collect.MapMaker.makeComputingMap(Lcom/google/common/base/Function;)Ljava/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap; from class org.jboss.weld.logging.WeldMessageConveyor
at org.jboss.weld.logging.WeldMessageConveyor.<init>(WeldMessageConveyor.java:61)
at org.jboss.weld.logging.WeldMessageConveyerFactory.getDefaultMessageConveyer(WeldMessageConveyerFactory.java:27)
at org.jboss.weld.logging.LoggerFactory.<init>(LoggerFactory.java:37)
at org.jboss.weld.logging.LoggerFactory.loggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:51)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.<clinit>(WeldBootstrap.java:126)
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

Any one has an idea why? My application uses Errai

Comment: Based on this [other issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-6007) you seem to be having a classloader issue with the version of guava that you use

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Based on @JoseM comment, [this link](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-6007) helped. A quick fix I applied for now was to downgrade my guava lib from `16.0.1` to `14.0.1`.

Comment: Reason of this error is that weblogic have dependency to older version of guava and you have never version in your dependencies. In newer version of guava `makeComputingMap` was removed. Downgrading Guava isn't best option. You should rather upgrade your weblogic server so it will have latest guava release.

Comment: Thanks so much had same problem with selenium here 
 'java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter'  , downgrading from 3.6.0 to 3.4.0 solved the problem. Hopefully it helps someone

Comment: Hello this Aditya Neurgaonkar. I am using guava-18.0.jar. I am not having this issue on windows. But on Unix environment. Can you confirm is it OS specific?

Comment: @AdityaNeurgaonkar, Java is not OS specific. Just check the libs that are being loaded by your application.