# Gradle sync failed for Android Studio 2.3.3 on Mac OS Sierra

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, macos-sierra, android-sdk-tools

I am newbie to Android Studio, I have installed Android Studio from official site: https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html for Max OS Sierra. Then installed SDK components (listed in below image):

[image: SDK default tools]

But still when I am creating new Android Project then it gives me Gradle sync failed error:

> Error:Cause: tried to access method
>   com.google.common.collect.Iterators.emptyIterator()Lcom/google/common/collect/UnmodifiableIterator;
>   from class org.gradle.api.internal.CompositeDomainObjectSet

I have tried many workarounds also changed the Gradle distributions to latest but still error persists.

Comment: I'm quite not sure but, it might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23957409/ava-lang-illegalaccesserror-tried-to-access-method-com-google-common-collect-ma

Comment: Yes, Its SDK installation need

Comment: I have installed SDK already..!

Comment: try reinstalling android studio..

Comment: I tried thrice from scratch.