# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.sameThreadExecutor

Tags: hazelcast, weblogic12c

I am getting the following exception when trying to deploy the :mancenter-3.1.3.war in to my Weblogic 12.

The fullstacktrace is :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'managementCenterContext' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'centralManager' while setting bean property 'centralManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'centralManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.hazelcast.webmonitor.service.CentralManager]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.sameThreadExecutor()Lcom/google/common/util/concurrent/ListeningExecutorService;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:329)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:107)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1387)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1128)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'centralManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.hazelcast.webmonitor.service.CentralManager]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.sameThreadExecutor()Lcom/google/common/util/concurrent/ListeningExecutorService;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1007)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:953)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:487)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.hazelcast.webmonitor.service.CentralManager]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.sameThreadExecutor()Lcom/google/common/util/concurrent/ListeningExecutorService;
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:163)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1000)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:953)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:487)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.sameThreadExecutor()Lcom/google/common/util/concurrent/ListeningExecutorService;
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.<clinit>(LocalCache.java:155)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache.<init>(LocalCache.java:4750)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache.<init>(LocalCache.java:4745)
    at com.google.common.cache.CacheBuilder.build(CacheBuilder.java:757)
    at com.hazelcast.webmonitor.service.CentralManager.<init>(CentralManager.java:63)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check your classpath and see what version of guava is being used by your WAR. The error suggests that the version of guava jar being found at runtime does not match the version that was used at compile time.

Sounds very similar to:

[Are Guava-11.0.2.jar conflicting with com.google.common_1.0.0.0_0-6.jar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13386474/are-guava-11-0-2-jar-conflicting-with-com-google-common-1-0-0-0-0-6-jar)

[Weblogic Guava issue when deploying application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13362523/weblogic-guava-issue-when-deploying-application)

Comment: I used preferred packages to use application specific classes .which helped to resolve this issue. Thanks Drew