# Guava 15.0 jar conflict in WebLogic 12c

Tags: guava, weblogic12c

I updated from guava 14.0.1 to 15.0 in an application that deploys on WebLogic 12c, and I get a java.lang.NoSuchMethodException during deployment that I've been unable to resolve:

```
Caused By: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.google.common.base.internal.Finalizer.startFinalizer(java.lang.Class, java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue, java.lang.ref.PhantomReference)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1624)
    at com.google.common.base.FinalizableReferenceQueue.getStartFinalizer(FinalizableReferenceQueue.java:302)
    at com.google.common.base.FinalizableReferenceQueue.<clinit>(FinalizableReferenceQueue.java:90)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:266)
    at com.oracle.injection.provider.weld.BasicResourceLoader.classForName(BasicResourceLoader.java:27)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployer.loadClass(BeanDeployer.java:107)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployer.addClass(BeanDeployer.java:77)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployer.addClasses(BeanDeployer.java:135)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployment.createBeans(BeanDeployment.java:184)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.deployBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:349)
    at com.oracle.injection.provider.weld.WeldInjectionContainer.deploy(WeldInjectionContainer.java:99)
    at com.oracle.injection.integration.CDIAppDeploymentExtension.initCdi(CDIAppDeploymentExtension.java:68)
    at com.oracle.injection.integration.CDIAppDeploymentExtension.activate(CDIAppDeploymentExtension.java:47)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.AppDeploymentExtensionFlow.activate(AppDeploymentExtensionFlow.java:37)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:729)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:258)
    at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.activate(EarDeployment.java:61)
    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:165)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:80)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:586)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:148)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:114)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:339)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:846)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1275)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:442)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:176)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:195)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:68)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:550)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:295)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:254)
```

I already have been using the WebLogic prefer-application-packages classloader filtering in my weblogic.xml file as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9688207/guava-and-weblogicclassnotfoundexception/17976553#17976553) in order to resolve a runtime conflict in WebLogic 12c as it seems to repackage an older version of the library. This had been working in guava 14.0.1, but does not in 15.0.

As far as I can tell, preferring the com.google.common.* package should include everything. Does this Finalizer class do something special that is happening before the classloader filtering happens, thereby trying to load the old version that appears to have a different API?

Is there an alternative solution to use the guava-15.0.jar packaged with the application instead of what is bundled with the server?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's an [open issue #1527](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=1527) targeting this problem (Guava 15 cannot be deployed to any JEE6 container) which occured after fixing [this one](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=1433). Please star and / or comment and wait for the fix ([comment #33](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=1433#c33) suggests that version 15.0.1 could be released in near furture).

**EDIT:**
Meanwhile, [the issue was resolved](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=1527#c17) by [new maven release](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/Release15#A_note_on_JEE6_/_CDI_1.0):

> ### A note on JEE6 / CDI 1.0
>
> A workaround added in Guava 15.0 to make it compatible with CDI 1.1
>   (used in JEE7 containers) caused problems for Guava with CDI 1.0 (used
>   in JEE6 containers).
>
> If you're using Guava in a CDI 1.0 environment, you should use
>   guava-15.0-cdi1.0.jar instead of the normal Guava jar. In Maven, the
>   dependency can be specified as:
>
> ```
> <dependency>
>   <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
>   <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
>   <version>15.0</version>
>   <classifier>cdi1.0</classifier>
> </dependency>
> ```

If you want to deploy on both JEE 6 and 7 servers, you must use Guava 13 or [wait until 16 is released](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=1527#c20).

Comment: Thanks for the information. I read through the threads, and tried removing the beans.xml from the guava-15.0.jar as WebLogic 12c is a JEE6 server, and that did seem to resolve the problem. I guess the best thing to do right now is just revert back to 14.0.1 until there's a new release of 15 that works without modification.

Answer (score 3):

As an aditional information, I landed on this question with a similar problem while upgrading to Weblogic 12c due to a conflit between WL and Guava (have tried with versions 11 and 18 of Guava).

I found the solution to be to explicitly prefer my application's lib. I set this on my weblogic.xml:

```
<prefer-application-packages>
  <package-name>com.google.common</package-name>
</prefer-application-packages>
```

Look at http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/wls/WLPRG/classloading.htm#WLPRG315 for the reference.

Comment: The package name should be 
<package-name>com.google.common</package-name>

Comment: Thanks Zeta for pointing that out. Don't know where I got the org part. Just redacted as per your suggestion.