# Guava 15.0 & JBoss 7.1.1

Tags: jboss7.x, guava

I deploy an application developped using Guava on JBoss 7.1.1.

On two different JBoss installations, we get the following exception when deploying the application.

My questions are:
- Are JBoss 7.1.1 and Guava 15.0 incompatible? It seems that it's the case. I can downgrade Guava to 14.0.1, but not lower given the features we use.
- How to fix this issue? Is there a way to tell JBoss to use my version of Guava?

```
16:02:58,719 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-1) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."c3-web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".WeldService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."c3-web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".WeldService: com.google.common.collect.ComputationException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
    at org.jboss.as.weld.services.WeldService.start(WeldService.java:83)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
Caused by: com.google.common.collect.ComputationException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
    at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingMapAdapter.get(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:397)
    at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer.loadClass(ClassTransformer.java:149)
    at org.jboss.weld.introspector.jlr.WeldClassImpl.<init>(WeldClassImpl.java:139)
    at org.jboss.weld.introspector.jlr.WeldClassImpl.of(WeldClassImpl.java:118)
    at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer$TransformTypeToWeldClass.apply(ClassTransformer.java:49)
    at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer$TransformTypeToWeldClass.apply(ClassTransformer.java:40)
    at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingValueReference.compute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:355)
    at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingSegment.compute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:184)
    at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingSegment.getOrCompute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:153)
    at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap.getOrCompute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:69)
    at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingMapAdapter.get(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:393)
    at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer.loadClass(ClassTransformer.java:149)
    at org.jboss.weld.introspector.jlr.WeldClassImpl.<init>(WeldClassImpl.java:139)
    at org.jboss.weld.introspector.jlr.WeldClassImpl.of(WeldClassImpl.java:118)
    at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer$TransformTypeToWeldClass.apply(ClassTransformer.java:49)
    at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer$TransformTypeToWeldClass.apply(ClassTransformer.java:40)
    at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingValueReference.compute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:355)
    at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingSegment.compute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:184)
    at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingSegment.getOrCompute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:153)
    at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap.getOrCompute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:69)
    at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingMapAdapter.get(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:393)
    at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer.loadClass(ClassTransformer.java:149)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployer.addClass(BeanDeployer.java:86)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployer.addClasses(BeanDeployer.java:115)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployment.createBeans(BeanDeployment.java:171)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.deployBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:336)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.WeldContainer.start(WeldContainer.java:82)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.services.WeldService.start(WeldService.java:76)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
    at org.jboss.weld.introspector.jlr.WeldConstructorImpl.<init>(WeldConstructorImpl.java:103)
    at org.jboss.weld.introspector.jlr.WeldConstructorImpl.of(WeldConstructorImpl.java:66)
    at org.jboss.weld.introspector.jlr.WeldClassImpl.<init>(WeldClassImpl.java:205)
    at org.jboss.weld.introspector.jlr.WeldClassImpl.of(WeldClassImpl.java:118)
    at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer$TransformTypeToWeldClass.apply(ClassTransformer.java:49)
    at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer$TransformTypeToWeldClass.apply(ClassTransformer.java:40)
    at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingValueReference.compute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:355)
    at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingSegment.compute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:184)
    at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingSegment.getOrCompute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:153)
    at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap.getOrCompute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:69)
    at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingMapAdapter.get(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:393)
    ... 32 more
```

Comment: See my answer in this question: [Guava 15.0 jar conflict in WebLogic 12c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19625086/guava-15-0-jar-conflict-in-weblogic-12c). It's the same issue.

Comment: Correct. I knew there were issues with JEE7, not with JEE6. Thanks!