# Which weblogic.xml file should I edit?

Tags: xml, weblogic, weblogic12c

I'm trying to fix some problems with a web app running on Weblogic 12c, and I've seen many users give advice to edit a file called weblogic.xml

This seems easy enough, except that there are multiple files called weblogic.xml in my directories. Which one am I supposed to edit? Specifically, I'm trying to do a fix like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9688207/guava-and-weblogicclassnotfoundexception).

Comment: Edit the xml file in your web app (war/ear file).... can you add more detail to the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to change the one found with your web application. In my case, I accessed it through Eclipse (because that's where my project was saved) under /src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/weblogic.xml. I was confused because I thought I was supposed to look in the Weblogic server or domain folders, where there were over a dozen weblogic.xml files.

Answer (score 1):

The weblogic.xml file is found under the WEB-INF directory along side the web.xml file.

Comment: There are about 20 WEB-INF directories.

Comment: Is this an EAR file with multiple web applications? If so you need to edit all of them. Depending on what you want to configure, there is an weblogic-application.xml file at the EAR level that applies to all web applications bunded in the EAR.

Comment: It's not. I was looking in the Weblogic folders when I should have been looking where my project was saved. That's why I was confused.